# Centering and vertically-aligning two side-by-side listings

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, listings

I have two listings I would like to place side-by-side in a figure. One of the listings is longer than the other. I want to have both listings centered horizontally and vertically aligned at the top (so that, in the image below, the first code block would be moved up to be approximately touching the red line). I have been enclosing my listings environments in `\begin{tabular}{c} ... \end{tabular}` to center them horizontally, and I have put them in two `minipage`s to have them side-by-side, but trying to vertically-align them by adding `[t]` to the minipages doesn't seem to work with the `tabular` environments. If I remove the `tabular` environments, I can vertically-align the two minipages like I want, but the listings aren't centered anymore.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is not as long
as the other code
            \end{lstlisting}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is a bit longer
than the other code
so I would like the
two listings to be
vertically aligned
at the top
            \end{lstlisting}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: Try `\parbox[t]...` in the place of minipages.

Comment: It looks like I can't use listings inside of a parbox (at least that's what I'm guessing from the cryptic listings error messages).

Comment: `tabular` also accepts the optional argument `[t]`. B.t.w., why do you need `tabular`s here?

Comment: I've tried adding `[t]` to the `tabular` before, but it didn't seem to change anything. I need the `tabular`s to center the listings; it's the best solution I've found.

Comment: What you did is unclear to me: was it `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}...`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may well not be the most minimal solution but it works, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage=0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is not as long
as the other code
            \end{lstlisting}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage=0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is a bit longer
than the other code
so I would like the
two listings to be
vertically aligned
at the top
            \end{lstlisting}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) to put contents side-by-side. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,
sidebyside align=top, 
halign=flush center,
%blankest % uncomment to remove colorbox
]
\centering
\begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is not as long
as the other code
\end{lstlisting}
\tcblower
\begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is a bit longer
than the other code
so I would like the
two listings to be
vertically aligned
at the top
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `blankest` option of `tcolorbox` can be used if you don't want the colorbox. Output with `blankest` option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `[t]`op-aligned `varwidth` with the `lstlisting` inside:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is not as long
as the other code
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{varwidth}\hfill
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
here is some code
that is a bit longer
than the other code
so I would like the
two listings to be
vertically aligned
at the top
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{varwidth}\hfill\mbox{}%
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting the same output as you even though I've copied and pasted what you provided and only added the `showframe` package and `frame=lr`. I'm still getting the code left-aligned.

https://i.imgur.com/bjT5laI.png